# IIS and COM+ Partitions: Failed to create ASP Application XXX due to invalid or missing COM Partition ID

Tags: iis, com+

I have an application that uses COM+ components. I am trying to make this application work on multiple applications in IIS. Each application has its own application pool.  That is why I need to separate COM+ Components one for each application. A way to isolate the COM+ Applications is to use COM+ Partitions.

I created the partitions in Component Services admin tool, on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. I created the partitions and I created a COM+ Application inside each one of them.
In IIS I have separate websites that run in different application pools. I configure each website to use partition and I assign it a partition GUID that exists.
After I set up IIS with the partition guid and I enable it to use partitions then, after an IISRESET, I run the website in browser and I receive a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. I looked into the event viewer and this is the error message: **Failed to create ASP Application XXX due to invalid or missing COM  Partition ID**.

If I disable the use of partitions in Component Services admin tool and disable the usage of partitions in IIS too then the application works.
I need to be able to use partition to allow multiple websites run in the same time with these COM+ objects.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research on this subject I have found the solution: do not use the PartitionId from IIS and do not enable partitions from IIS either. Leave them to default values.

The solution to this is the following: Each partition should be assigned as default partition for one user and each IIS Application (and each App pool) should run on the same users that the default partitions use. 
So basically if you have two IIS Applications named: web1 and web2, and two app pools: app1 and app2, two users user1 and user2 and two partitions: part1 and part2.
web1 should run under user1 and app1 should run also under user1 (app1 is the application pool for web1). Then in Component Services user1 should have the default partition: part1. Then when the web1 will search for a COM+ component it will first try to search for it in the partition assigned to the user of that IIS application: user1. User1 has the default partition part1 so it will find it.

HINT: To enable com+ partitions on windows server 2008 R2 go to Component Services > My Computer > Right click on it > Properties > Options Tab > Check Enable partitions and also the other one: Check local store when choosing partition for user .
Partitions can only be enabled in Windows Server editions. This option is disabled in Windows 7 and I couldn't find a way to enable it.

Hope this helps.

Do not forget to add COM+ Applications under each Partition and to add the users there too so that the users can access them. So Add users in Partition Roles and also in COM+ Partition Users directory, under My Computer in Component Services.